# How do I make my reactjs-for-wordpress-plugin content visible to Google?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, shortcode

I have created a Wordpress plugin using react and I'm using it as a shortcode. I recently realized that the content within the react app isn't visible with the view source option from code, and even google isn't able to read it for SEO.

How do I make it visible to google like a regular html page ?

My build folder contains the following:

- index.asset.php
- index.css
- index.js

I tried a pre-rendering npm package but it didn't work - the app didn't appear within the page. I'm using wp-scripts in my project.

Answer (score 0):

React app is being rendered on the client-side by default, which means that it's not included in the initial HTML source that's sent to the browser.

To make your React app visible to search engines, you'll need to implement server-side rendering (SSR) for your WordPress plugin.

You can check [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/improve-app-performance-react-server-side-rendering/) to get better ideas about tools and frameworks that will help you enable SSR for React

Comment: Hi Yazan, thanks very much for your reply. It looks like other frameworks have tools for SSR and WP as well.

Comment: It's great to hear that my answer was helpful. Depending on your specific needs and preferences, it may be worth exploring those options as well and comparing them to the framework you were originally considering.